# How to set border of \resizebox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, resize, pgfornament

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\usepackage{labels, fontawesome}

\setmainfont{Holden}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning, % for left=of, above=of etc.
  calc % for let syntax used in second example
}
\LabelCols=1%         Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=1%         Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=2mm%      Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=2mm%     Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=2mm%       Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm%    Space to leave at bottom of sheet
\numberoflabels=1
\begin{document}
% 
% \begin{center}

    \newsavebox{\orn}
    \savebox{\orn}{
      \resizebox{15cm}{6cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
font=\large
\node [Black] (text) {Vaijan\XeTeXglyph83s Honey};
% in all of the below some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the width of the ornaments
% set width of these ornaments to half the text node's width
   \node [below= 1mm of text] (below) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{69}};
   \node [above = 1mm of text] (above) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{69}};



% % use \n2 for ornament width here
   \node [rotate=-90, below left=5mm and 1mm of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{46}}; %M left
   \node [rotate=90, below right=5mm and 1mm of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{46}}; %N right
% % and \n1 here
   \node [above=1mm of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=4cm]{71}};%top H
  % 
% %   node [anchor=south] (bottom) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
% % and 25% of width for the corner ornaments
   \node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{63}}; %top left
   \node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{63}}; %top right
%    % draw frame
%   \vspace{2cm};
  \node [below=1mm of below] (addressLineUp) at (below.south) {\pgfornament[width=3.5cm]{88}};
  \setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  font=\normalsize
  \node [Brown, below=1mm of addressLineUp, align=center] (address) {Md.Al-Helal, CSE, DU\\ 01515611989\\\faFacebookSquare{}Honey\&Date};
  \node [below=1mm of address] (addressLineDown) {\pgfornament[width=3.5cm]{88}};
  \node [below=1mm of addressLineDown] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=4cm]{71}};%G
%   \node [below=of addressLineDown] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=6cm,symmetry=h]{71}};
  \node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=h]{63}}; %bottom left
\node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=c]{63}}; % bottom right
% \fill [red] (0, 10) rectangle (-5, 15);
\node[anchor=west, rotate=-90, right=1cm of right] (rightBoxLeft) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{46}};
\node[anchor=west, right=1mm of rightBoxLeft, align=center] (rightBoxText) {Honey has natural\\ healing power};
\node[anchor=west, rotate=90, right=1mm of rightBoxText] (rightBoxRight) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{46}};
\node [above=2cm of rightBoxText] (rightBoxTop) {\pgfornament[width=4cm]{71}};%top H
\node [below=2cm of rightBoxText] (rightBoxBottom) {\pgfornament[width=4cm]{71}};%top H
\node [anchor=north west] at (rightBoxTop.north -| rightBoxLeft.south)  {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{63}}; %top left
\node [anchor=north east] at (rightBoxTop.north -| rightBoxRight.south) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{63}}; %top right
%    % draw frame
\node [anchor=south west] at (rightBoxBottom.south -| rightBoxLeft.south) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=h]{63}}; %bottom left
\node [anchor=south east] at (rightBoxBottom.south -| rightBoxRight.south) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=c]{63}}; % bottom right
% \fill [red] (0, 10) rectangle (-5, 15);

% \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

}
    }
    \begin{labels}
    \usebox{\orn}
% \end{center}
\end{labels}
\end{document}
```

By Changing the width of the pgfornament elements the output shrink/enlarge. I don't understand for which measurement the design fit with my predefined area.

Here, 1st output box is located upper to the right part.

If the `\resizebox` shows the area I defined using command then I can easily understand whether my content's take more space than defined or not.

[image]

I want to get like this. This border shows that I have more space to enlarge my pgfornament element. Here the red border shows the resizebox area I defined.

Comment: If you have line breaks in code like after `\savebox{\orn}{` you will get a space character there, leading to a larger visible white margin. You need to comment out that line break, e.g. `\savebox{\orn}{%`, to avoid that. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/2975)

Comment: Also have a look at the `adjustbox` package which allows you to box, resize and frame any content with easy while removing spurious spaces around the content.

Comment: you have two space tokens to the left: `\savebox{\orn}{SPACE \resizebox{15cm}{6cm}{SPACE` and at the end have multiple space tokens and a paragraph break, always beware of adding white space.